# Unable to use a variable value twice in the same PHP file

Tags: php, html, variables, isset

I have written a few lines in php to display data and then edit it and save it when the user clicks on 'Save' button. This is just for testing hence I haven't used a lot of verification of password and sanitization. The main aim is to display and update.

The Username and password is coming from display.html (user & pass). The data picked up from 2 tables member_login_info and member_master and the primary key is cust_id. The record is displayed all right, but when trying to update the record, the $cid value seems missing and hence cant update.

The $cid value can be displayed in the second set of php code, but once inside the function if(isset($_POST['edit'])) it can no longer be echo'd.

I know there is a simple mistake somewhere, but I cant figure it out.
Your help will be much appreciated.

```html
<?php
session_start();

include 'db_connect.php';

$user  = (isset($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['user']) ? $_POST['user'] : "");
$pass  = (isset($_POST['pass']) && !empty($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass'] : "");


$sql = mysql_query("SELECT member_login_info.cust_id, member_master.fname, member_master.lname, member_master.cust_dob 
          FROM member_login_info INNER JOIN member_master
          ON member_login_info.cust_id = member_master.cust_id
          WHERE member_login_info.profilename = '$user' AND member_login_info.password = sha1('$pass') ");
    
$result=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

$fname = $result["fname"];
$lname = $result["lname"];
$dob   = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($result["cust_dob"]));
$cid   = $result["cust_id"];

// $_SESSION['cid'] = $result["cust_id"];
?>

<div id="edit_data"> 
 <fieldset style="width:30%">
 <legend>Edit information</legend> 
 
 <table border="0">
  <form name="edit" method="POST" >
 <tr>   
 <td>First Name:</td><td>
 <input name="fname" type="text" id="fname" value="<?php echo $fname; ?>" > </td> 
 </tr>
 
 <tr> 
 <td>Last Name:</td><td> 
 <input name="lname" type="text" id="lname" value="<?php echo $lname; ?>"> </td> 
 </tr>
 
 <tr> 
 <td>Date of Birth:</td><td> 
 <input name="dob" type="text" id="dob" value="<?php echo $dob; ?>"> </td> 
 </tr>
 <tr> 
  
 <tr> 
 <td><input id="exit" type="submit" name="exit" value="Exit" onclick="window.location.href='display.html'"></td>
 <td><input id="edit" type="submit" name="edit" value="Save"></td>  
 </tr> 
 </form> 
 </table> 
 </fieldset>  
 </div>
 
 <?php
 echo "$cid";
 if(isset($_POST['edit'])) {
  
 $fname = $_POST['fname'];
 $lname = $_POST['lname'];  
 $dob   = $_POST['dob'];
 
 $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE member_master SET fname = '$fname', lname = '$lname', cust_dob = '$dob' 
      WHERE cust_id = '$cid' ");
 }
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question exactly?  Is it, "Where is the simple mistake in my code?"

Comment: Forms don't use named attributes, elements do. Therefore `if(isset($_POST['edit'])){ // nothing inside this will ever work. }` - Use a hidden type of element.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['edit'])) { ... }` is not a function.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. The issue is data is not being updated.

Comment: Fred-ii, can you pls explain in a little detail. I'm new to php. How to use a hidden type of element?

Answer (score 0):

Your code expects a user and a pass to be given to it through POST. When you click on the "Save" button, the form is submitted, and because there is nothing that specifies the value of of both user and pass, the following snippet sets both variables to `""`.

```
$user   = (isset($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['user']) ? $_POST['user'] : "");
$pass   = (isset($_POST['pass']) && !empty($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass'] : "");
```

The simple way of fixing this would be to add two hidden inputs to your form, one with the name set to `user` and the value set to whatever `$user` holds, and similarly for `pass` and `$pass`:

```
<input name="user" value="<?php echo $user; ?>" type="hidden" />
<input name="pass" value="<?php echo $pass; ?>" type="hidden" />
```

However, **this is very insecure**. If your connection is not encrypted the credentials are sent in clear-text, and given that there is no csrf/repeat token, it is vulnerable to both csrf and replay attacks.

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving the `cid` based on `user` and `pass`. Then, you are submitting a change of some other data, without resubmitting `user` and `pass`.

Your logic to retrieve the `cid` will then fail, and therefore your update will fail.

You could either add the `cid` as a hidden field or - which would be better - store the users login state (and cid) in the session, once he successfully autehenticated:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT member_login_info.cust_id, member_master.fname, member_master.lname, member_master.cust_dob 
          FROM member_login_info INNER JOIN member_master
          ON member_login_info.cust_id = member_master.cust_id
          WHERE member_login_info.profilename = '$user' AND member_login_info.password = sha1('$pass') ");

$result=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

if (mysql_num_rows() == 1){
  $_SESSION["fname"] = $result["fname"];
  $_SESSION["lname"] = $result["lname"];
  $_SESSION["dob"]   = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($result["cust_dob"]));
  $_SESSION["cid"]   = $result["cust_id"];
```

}

then, when you try to update data, refer to the session variable `$_SESSION["cid"]` rather than to any `$_POST` or `$_GET` Variable.

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE member_master SET fname = '$fname', lname   = '$lname', cust_dob = '$dob' 
                WHERE cust_id = '".$_SESSION['cid']."' ");
```

Sidenode: Your code is vulnerable to SQL-Injections! `mysql*`-methods are deprecated, you should use prepared statements instead!